# How to add shortcut key by bash script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, compiz

We are working on a kiosk mode in Linux Ubuntu. We would like to define a shortcut by command line (bash script). Is this possible? We would like to setup our kiosk mode automatically by a bash script. So creating a new shortcut via Compiz isn't possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to create a shorcut inside X.org to launch a bash script?

Comment: Yes just like you would define a new shortcut in the system settings but via command line

Answer (score 2):

The shortcuts usually depend on the window manager you're using. If you're using Ubuntu you should have Gnome as default windomanager so you could use the `Gnome Control Center` to set the shortcuts you want.

Another way, is use a tool like `Xbindkeys` which is indipendent from the window manager and reads the key configuration from a simple text file usually `~/.xbindkeysrc`.

So you could install `Xbindkeys` in your system with:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Then in the `bash` script you could add a new entry in the `~/xbindkeysrc` config file to add your shortcut.